# Webforms: Update RadioButtonList within UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel, radiobuttonlist

I'am trying to make a web page with one Question and Answers under it. The Question is an  and the answers are a RadioButtonList. I want to change the question and the answers with other question and answers using ajax(in UpdatePanel) after a submit button is clicked. Here is my html:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="QuestionUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAnswersData"></asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitAnswerButton" Text="Submit Answer" OnClick="SubmitAnswerButton_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My ScriptManager is defined in the masterpage.

And the codebehind:

```
private int currentQuestion = 0;
private int currentGameId = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.currentGameId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        LoadFirstQuestion();
    }

    private void LoadFirstQuestion()
    {
        this.QuestionLabel.Text = this.games.GetById(this.currentGameId).Questions.FirstOrDefault().Text;
        currentQuestion++;
    }

public IQueryable<string> GetAnswersData()
    {
        var answers = new List<string>();
        answers.Add(this.games.GetById(currentGameId).Questions.Skip(currentQuestion - 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().WrongAnswerOne);
        answers.Add(this.games.GetById(currentGameId).Questions.Skip(currentQuestion - 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().WrongAnswerTwo);
        answers.Add(this.games.GetById(currentGameId).Questions.Skip(currentQuestion - 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().WrongAnswerThree);
        answers.Add(this.games.GetById(currentGameId).Questions.Skip(currentQuestion - 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().TrueAnswer);

        return answers.AsQueryable();
    }

    protected void SubmitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfCorrectAnswer();
        currentQuestion++;
        this.RadioButtonList.DataSource = GetAnswersData();
        this.RadioButtonList.DataBind();
        this.QuestionUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

So, I am getting the error on the `this.RadioButtonList.DataBind();` line which is saying:

> {"DataSource or DataSourceID cannot be defined on 'RadioButtonList'
>   when it uses model binding."}

Thanks in advance! :)

---

I found a solution for the problem. I just had to change the return type of the `GetAnswersData()` method to `IList<string>`.